# How to get the value of the attr_accessible within model class Rails + Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm trying to set some metadata for an mp3 object that I'm trying to upload to my

AWS S3 through Rails using paperclip.

```
class myClass < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :mp3, file_name
    attr_accessor :mp3, file_name

    has_attached_file :mp3,
        // some s3 credential info + bucket
        :s3_metadata => {
            :name => //get the name attr of the instance that I'm trying to save
        }
```

This is within the Model.rb file.

The question is, if I want to set the metadata to some attr that this instance has,

how to I access that value here?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `.attributes` on an object of class `ActiveRecord::Base` will return a hash of all of the attributes.

In this case, you **may** be able to use a lambda, something like

```
name: ->{ method_that_returns_the_name }
```

You **probably** won't set the file name in the class declaration. Did you try

```
@object.file_name = 'My File Name'
@object.save
```

If you would like to take the name from somewhere else, you could use a filter.

```
before_save do 
  self.file_name = "image-#{self.id}"
end
```

Comment: but how do I do that within the model class itself?

Comment: Are you just trying to change the file name?

Comment: I've edited the question. So basically inside the paperclip's 'has_attached_file', I want to set the metadata as the 'file_name' attribute of this model.

Comment: Then do you know what paperclip method I can use to set the S3 metadata after the instance is created?

Comment: Did you try writing `@object.file_name = 'New File Name'`?

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this in your example, you could use:

```
class myClass < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :mp3, file_name
    attr_accessor :mp3, file_name

    has_attached_file :mp3,
        // some s3 credential info + bucket
        s3_headers: lambda { |attachment|
          { 'x-amz-meta-name' => attachment.instance.name }
        }
```

It doesn't look like s3_metadata will take a proc but you can use s3_headers instead by prefixing the header with "x-amz-meta-".  You can access the instance of "myClass" through attachment.instance in the lambda.